# What is a convenient way to link with an so/dll library located in the subfolder of the project?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am a cabal newbie. I have a cabal project and in its root there is a folder `clib/*` with dynamic libraries for multiple OSes:

```
clib/
  `---my/
       `---libSomething.so
       `---Something.dll
       `---...
```

And I have to link the application with these libraries (they are written in C, Go...). I refer them with `extra-libraries:` cabal setting. But now I have to set the folder where they are located (`./clib/my/`). I tried `extra-lib-dirs:` setting in the `cabal.project` but it may not be relative - so it does not work.

I supposed there is some placeholder like `${projectroot}` or similar that can be used as a prefix, but I cannot find one in cabal's documentation.

The path cannot be absolute because the code base is shared with several developers in Git repository and all of them use different OSes and file system layouts as well.

What is the convenient way to link shared objects located in sub-directories of the project (not in system standard places) for different OSes (Mac, Windows, Linux)?

Comment: The cabal file has a section for [foreing libraries](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-package.html?highlight=platform#foreign-libraries). I don't know how to use it or if it easy, but you should read the documentation

Comment: It seems foreign-library is for a lib available with its source code only. Unfortunately, my libs (Go) are not my, I consume them as .so/.dll/.dylib. But anyways, thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build from source, I recommend that. Have a look at the `c-sources`/`cc-options` and `cxx-sources`/`cxx-options` fields. If not, then newer cabal provides an `extra-bundled-libraries` field that is like `extra-libraries` for relative paths but appears from the documentation to be extremely restrictive on the name and location of your library.

Comment: Wow, really, there is such option! I just tried it, but got `myapp-0.1.0.0: cannot find any of ["libmylib.a","libmylib_p.a","libmylib- ghc9.2.3.so","libmylib-ghc9.2.3.dylib","mylib-ghc9.2.3.dll"]
on library path (use --force to override)` while I have `Clibmylib-ghc9.2.3.so, Clibmylib.so, libClibmylib-ghc9.2.3.so, libcmylib-ghc9.2.3.so, libCmylib-ghc9.2.3.so, libmylib-ghc9.2.3.so, libmylib.so` (cabal is 3.8.1.0). Also it seems no way to use a lib from subfolder of the project. Maybe it's time to open an issue in cabal bug tracker.

Comment: It seems it depends on the version of GHC also, there were a set of bugs related to extra-bundled-libraries in cabal and GHC. Currently, I have not idea how I have to name the .so library for the cabal 3.8.1.0, GHC 9.2.3, Linux x86_64 environment.

Comment: I accepted the answer and opened a bug: actually the library should be inside `dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.2.3/XXX-0.1.0.0/build/` with 2 names: `libmylib-ghc9.2.3.so` for cabal and `libmylib.so` for the linker. It's weird, maybe there is more correct way to ensure its existence there, but I don't know.

Comment: @RandomB I think for a non-Haskell library, it should be `libCmylib.so`... one of the few combos you didn't try!

Comment: This may be some kind of answer: https://www.codinginfinity.me/posts/haskell-and-cpp/